# MagicalRecord truncateAll importFromObject at the same time, and get the wrong result

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

Here's the problem.

I use MagicalRecord to deal with Core Data.

I have a `NSManagedObject` named `Category`.

First, App will get all the `Category` from WebService, and it's `30 items` now.

Than when it get `Response`, App will clean the `Category` first, And add the `30 items`
one by one, Than save all changes.

```
[Category truncateAll];
for...loop...
  [Category importFromObject:categoryDictionayFromJson];
[[NSManagedObjectContext rootSavingContext] saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
```

It's `30 items` by `[Category findAll]` now.
Then, the `Category` will be used later in `Another ViewController`.

```
[Category findAll];
```

My problem for now is, when App used `Category`, it's became `31 items` or `32` or `34`...
very stranger to me.

I'm sure the Server return `30 items`, but the extra items looks like the correct data on Server like correct record which just return from Server this time.

I'm just wonder what can I do for the next to find the problem, or to solve the problem.

Here's something that I have tried:

1. debug the `[Category findAll]` in every step to trace where the change happened. no lucky.
2. update the MagicalRecord to the latest version. no lucky.

What can I do, or what I miss?

**Update**

After debug more depth. I find the root cause:

There's another request in the `Another ViewController`, and that one will return a list of `Object`, and this `Object` include property which named `Category`, this kind of relationship will lead to save extra `Category` if that one is not saved in the `Category` before. So, very clever, right.

Just because I only need this `Category` to used as `Part of ALL`, and Magical Record will help me to import `All`.

**Update, Fixed**

Base on the root cause, I fixed it by include another property named like `isFunctinoOneUsed` for `Object`, and set it to YES when first request to get it. And for the `Another ViewController` to use, just include an condition `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.isFunctinoOneUsed = YES"]` to get the needed result.

Comment: Have you tried saving your context immediately after your truncateAll, and before your import calls? Also, make sure you use the proper contexts with the inContext: parameter.

Comment: @casademora I called `[[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext1] saveToPersistentStoreAndWait]` after truncateAll immediately everytime. And I use the `[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext1]`, so I think the context is OK.

Comment: @casademora And why I use `defaultContext1` not `defaultContext`, because when try to commit to apple, it notice that the `defaultContext` hasBeen used by apple, I should not use it.some kind of that.

Comment: Apple's code does not have a defaultContext method or object anywhere. Not sure what conflict you're seeing to get that issue.

Comment: It's just says that defaultContext is kind of non-public method. And My problem already been fixed. The reason I have just updated above.